# MvvmCross + Android notifcation click getting viewmodel as null

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-notifications, mvvmcross

I have being using Xamarin and MvvmCross to create a cross platform application.

On android platform I need to show notification.

On notification click user should land to the MainView screen. everything works as required.

The problem occurs when the app has been removed from the back ground and then notification arrives and user click on the notification then the MainViewModel is null.

Below is how I show the notification.

```
private void NotifyNotification(string title, string message)
        {


    var notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;            
    int unique = 1;
    //uiIntent
    Intent uiIntent;

    uiIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainView));

    uiIntent.PutExtra("AppNotification", true);
    uiIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop | ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
    //pendingIntent
    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, uiIntent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this);
    Notification notification = builder.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                              .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.notificationIcon).SetTicker(message)
                              .SetAutoCancel(true).SetContentTitle(title).SetNumber(DroidConstants.NotifyCounter)
                              .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.All)
                              .SetContentText(message).Build();
        notificationManager.Notify(unique, notification);            
}
```

Below is my MainView Class code

```
 public abstract class BaseMainView : BaseView<MainViewModel>
    {

    }

        [Activity(Label = "New Tasks",
              NoHistory = false,
              Icon = "@drawable/icon",
              Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light",
              LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTask,//setted to single task to handle stack issue
            //ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait,
              UiOptions = Android.Content.PM.UiOptions.SplitActionBarWhenNarrow)]
        /*,
              ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize*/
    public class MainView : BaseMainView
    {      

        public new MainViewModel ViewModel
        {
          get { return base.ViewModel; }
          set { base.ViewModel = value; }
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);            
            // Set up View to be shown
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainView);
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MainView, MainViewModel>();
            //Code to map binding with controls
            set.Apply();

        }
        protected override void OnNewIntent(Android.Content.Intent intent)
        {
            //When is in background or running then this get called and I simple perform the action required.
        }
    }
```

Note:- I have setted the LaunchMode of this activity to be SingleTask.

> LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTask

Because of which when the app is in foreground or background on notification click OnNewIntent is get called and able to perform the logic over there. But, when the app is removed from the background and the notification arrive then on notification click OnCreate Method is called and there I am getting the MainViewModel as empty.

Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks,
Aaman

Answer (score 1):

The default view model loading mechanism within MvvmCross uses a special `Extra` within the `Intent` to help identify the ViewModel request.

You can see how it does this for a normal request here - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.2/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Views/MvxAndroidViewsContainer.cs#L134

```
    public virtual Intent GetIntentFor(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        var viewType = GetViewType(request.ViewModelType);
        if (viewType == null)
        {
            throw new MvxException("View Type not found for " + request.ViewModelType);
        }

        var converter = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxNavigationSerializer>();
        var requestText = converter.Serializer.SerializeObject(request);

        var intent = new Intent(_applicationContext, viewType);
        intent.PutExtra(ExtrasKey, requestText);

        AdjustIntentForPresentation(intent, request);

        return intent;
    }
```

If you wanted to use this code for the basis of your Intent, you could do this using code like (for example):

```
  var request = MvxViewModelRequest<MyViewModel>.GetDefaultRequest();
  var intent = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidViewModelRequestTranslator>().GetIntentFor(request);
```

Obviously, it's just an `Intent` so you can add extra fields to it if you want to.

---

Alternatively, you don't have to use the default ViewModel loading mechanism - you can replace this with your own mechanism if you prefer.